# How i can Get from Div Top and add to this div top + 25?

Tags: javascript

I tried to add this Div `top: + 25` but I wasted 6 hours and no have more ideas how I can achieve it.

I tried like this:

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("GAME_NPC").offsetTop;
var testDiv2 = document.getElementById("GAME_CHARACTER").offsetTop += "32px";

//alert(testDiv2);
if (testDiv == testDiv2) {}
```

But this doesn't work.

```
            var testDiv = document.getElementById("GAME_NPC").offsetTop;
        var testDiv2 = document.getElementById("GAME_CHARACTER");
        var top = testDiv2.offsetTop;

        top += 32; //that one is int

        testDiv2.style.top = top + "px"; // and that one should be string with 'px'

        if(testDiv2 == testDiv){


        }
```

this also doesn't work

test.css

```
#GAME_CHARACTER {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 32px;
height: 48px;
left: 32px;
top: 32px;
z-index:200;
}

#GAME_NPC {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:120px;
    width: 96px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url(http://xxx/npc.gif) no-repeat center;
}
```

html code:

```
            <DIV id="GAME_CHARACTER" class="left-stand" style="background-image: url(http://xxx/character.png);"></DIV>

        <DIV id="GAME_MAP2"><DIV id="GAME_NPC"></DIV></DIV>
```

Comment: Offset top is read only, it will not move elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop use css instead.

Comment: plus : there is no chance that an arithmetic operation can be carried out on character strings

Comment: Do you want to move div according to webpage top or according its parent element. You can user `margin` or `padding` for second case and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` for the first case

Comment: Is `top:120pox;` a typo in the question, or is this a copy-paste snippet from your actual program?

Comment: @Arfeo yes, my mistake. sorry

Comment: testDiv2 is an element and testDiv is offsetTop of the "GAME_NPC" div. They by definition will never be equal. I guess you need to have if(testDiv2.offsetTop == testDiv)

Comment: @VegettoSan Your question is unclear, but as far as i can tell you wanted to add 25pixels to testDiv2's current position am i right? if yes then you could also try to do this with `transform: translateY(25px)`. transform will offset the element with added +25px. hope this helps.

Comment: @maximelian1986 but character px is updated when done walking so this will not work because character will walk on image npc, so i need +32px before character will walk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will all 25px to whatever the current top is, which should achieve your desired effect.

```
function addTop(element, px){
    element.style.top = (Number(element.style.top.replace(/\D/g, "")) + px) + "px";
}
addTop(document.getElementById("GAME_CHARACTER"), 25);
```

Comment: but now how i can check if testDiv == testDiv2+32px?
i don't need permament +32px just for checking

Comment: I think that's the wrong way to approach the problem. You don't need to actually move one div in order to compare it to another. Just do something like: if(testDiv.offsetTop == testDiv2.offsetTop + 32){}

Comment: thank you!, i made mistake because i use +32 but i need -32 ......... thanks!

Comment: No problem! An important thing to note this that wrapping a number in quotes means it's a string and NOT a number anymore. You can't expect to be able to do traditional math with a string. It won't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Grab element offsetTop, update it and set updated value to whatever element you want. Remember append "px" when updating it.

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("my-div-id");
var top = testDiv.offsetTop;

top += 32; //that one is int

testDiv.style.top = top + "px"; // and that one should be string with 'px'
```

Comment: Please add relevant css to your post, this might help

Comment: Debug it and see that parameter "top" is updated. Not sure what you trying to achieve, I thought you were trying to update style "top" of element.